# Using @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to add the same menu on different pages and I tired to use `@Html.Partial`
I created the partial view `_ProjectMenu.cshtml`

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_AssociationManagement, "AssociationManagement", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_WarehouseAndInventory, "WarehouseAndInventory", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_ElectronicDocumentManagement, "ElectronicDocumentManagement", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_Medicine, "Medicine", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_BankingSector, "BankingSector", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_Insurance, "Insurance", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_Websites, "Websites", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_WebApplication, "WebApplication", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_DataWarehouse, "DataWarehouse", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_MobileApplications, "MobileApplications", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_TrafficManagement, "TrafficManagement", "Projects")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_LearningSystems, "LearningSystems", "Projects")</li>
    <li class="sector">@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Project_Sector, "Sector", "Projects")</li>
</ul>
```

and then I added this code on my page

```
<div class="span4">
    @Html.Partial("_ProjectMenu")
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.
I guess I need to add some code in controller, but I don't know how to do it?

**UPD** I placed my partial view file in `Shared` folder
and I got this exception
[image]

Comment: Where did you place your partial view? Put it in the `Shared` folder.

Comment: "doesn't work." - usually, when things don't work, they don't work in *specific* ways. Do you get no content? An error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view is called **_ProjectMenu** and you are referencing **_ProjectsMenu**